# Trouble Converting From GeoGridPosition with Equirectangular Projection

Tags: bugs, geography

A simplified version of my code is:

```
mesh = DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[{-180, -90}, {180, 90}], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 360*180/100]
coords = MeshCoordinates[mesh];
cgrid = GeoGridPosition[Append[-1000] /@ coords, "Equirectangular", 
   "GRS80"];
cxyz = GeoPositionXYZ@cgrid;
cgeod = GeoPosition@cxyz
cgeod[[1, All, 3]] // MinMax
(* {-1000, 1000} *)
```

So, apparently, points on an Equirectangular map corresponding to poles, initially with a height of -1000 meters over GRS80 reference ellipsoid, are converted to points with a height of +1000 meters.

This in turn causes problem of extrapolation for an interpolating function defined only over GRS80 reference ellipsoid in terms of GeoPositionXYZ coordinates.

There is something wrong in my approach?

Comment: Thank you very much for reporting this problem! There is indeed a numeric instability at the pole that makes GeoPosition[GeoPositionXYZ[GeoPosition[{90., 0., -1000.}]]] return the wrong sign of the elevation.

Comment: @jose Do you think this happens in the first GeoPositionXYZ or in the subsequent @GeoPosition? I also noticed different behavior with different map projections...

Comment: The xyz vector is correct. The problem happens in the conversion from xyz back to latlon. On an ellipsoid this conversion requires solving a cubic equation, and it seems some choice of sign is failing, due to small numerical errors.